# Validar campo ao mudar para outro campo

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho os seguintes campos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Neles são cadastrados os valores permitidos pelo Correios para calcular o frete. Apesar de ter limitado os campos com os valores aceitos:

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">
        <input class="form-control" name="Largura"  type="number" min="11" max="105" placeholder="Largura" value="<?php if($_POST["Largura"]){ echo $_POST["Largura"]; }else{ echo "11"; } ?>">
      <span class="input-group-addon" style="background-color: #F8F8F8">cm</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">
    <input  type="number" min="2" max="105" name="Altura" class="form-control" placeholder="Altura" value="<?php if($_POST["Altura"]){ echo $_POST["Altura"]; }else{ echo "2"; } ?>">
        <span class="input-group-addon" style="background-color: #F8F8F8">cm</span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3">
  <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">
    <input  type="number" min="16" max="105" name="Comprimento" class="form-control"  placeholder="Comprimento" value="<?php if($_POST["Comprimento"]){ echo $_POST["Comprimento"]; }else{ echo "16"; } ?>">
        <span class="input-group-addon" style="background-color: #F8F8F8">cm</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">
     <input type="text" name="Peso" id="peso" class="form-control"   placeholder="Peso (ex: 0.300, 1.000)" maxlength="5" value="<?php echo $_POST["Peso"]; ?>" data-inputmask="'alias': '9.999'">
         <span class="input-group-addon" style="background-color: #F8F8F8">kg</span>
        </div>
</div>
```

Gostaria de saber se é possível ao mudar de campo e caso o valor seja inferior o superior ao permitido, aparecer uma mensagem automática, sem a necessidade de clicar no botão "Salvar" para isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este código irá funcionar apenas nos `inputs` tipo `number`, exibindo uma mensagem abaixo do campo:

```js
$('.input-group input[type=number]').on('blur focus', function(e){
   if(e.type == 'blur'){
      var min_ = parseFloat($(this).attr('min'));
      var max_ = parseFloat($(this).attr('max'));
      var val_ = parseFloat($(this).val());
      if(val_ < min_ || val_ > max_){
         $(this).closest('.col-lg-3').append('<span class="err_msg" style="color: #f00;">O valor não pode ser inferior a '+min_+' ou superior a '+max_+'!</span>');
      }
   }else{
      $(this).closest('.col-lg-3').find('.err_msg').remove();
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">
        <input class="form-control" name="Largura"  type="number" min="11" max="105" placeholder="Largura" value="">
      <span class="input-group-addon" style="background-color: #F8F8F8">cm</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">
    <input  type="number" min="2" max="105" name="Altura" class="form-control" placeholder="Altura" value="">
        <span class="input-group-addon" style="background-color: #F8F8F8">cm</span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3">
  <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">
    <input  type="number" min="16" max="105" name="Comprimento" class="form-control"  placeholder="Comprimento" value="">
        <span class="input-group-addon" style="background-color: #F8F8F8">cm</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">
     <input type="text" name="Peso" id="peso" class="form-control"   placeholder="Peso (ex: 0.300, 1.000)" maxlength="5" value="11" data-inputmask="'alias': '9.999'">
         <span class="input-group-addon" style="background-color: #F8F8F8">kg</span>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Show de bola DvD. Vou adaptar o seu código. Obrigado!

Comment: @Fox.11 Valeu! Boa sorte!